# How can I add a relative data setting in Acumatica KPIs?

Tags: erp, acumatica

How do I setup a KPI that can include the current and previous Month and/or periods? The dates need to default to the current period and/or dates?

Comment: Please include more information to your question, what do you call a KPI, a dashboard?, an inquiry?. And also from where to you take your information from, a page, an inquiry?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with determining what data you want in your KPI and where the data resides.  Good place to start is the Generic inquiries where you can search for tables and may contain your info.  try the keyword Period or History as these will typically contain summery information.

Create the inquiry with the data that you are looking for and then publish on your dashboards.  If you cannot find tables that contain the data, you can also create your own DAC and use them  in your inquiries.

if you have a specific example of what you want to see, post it as another question on what you did, what trouble you had and you can get a more specific answer for your need.